# My javascript is only working, it's not changing the text

Tags: javascript

My script is not working, I am just trying to change my text in a div element

Here is my javascript code

```
var jumbo = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron");
var button = document.getElementById("changebg")

function changeBackground(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron").innerHTML = "BLASAKLSJL";
}
```

And this is my html code :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <button id="changebg" onclick="changeBackground()">
  CLICK ME
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** will return an array of objects you need to specify the one you want to update.

**Example :**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[index].innerHTML = "BLASAKLSJL";
____________________________________________^^^^^^^
```

If there's just **one element** with class `jumbotron` so you could use [0] :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0].innerHTML = "BLASAKLSJL";
```

If there's **multiple elements** then you should loop through them :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron");

for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
     elements[i].innerHTML = "new html here";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I do that? and also, there's only one jumbotron here? what if there are multiple? how do I specify?

Comment: If there's just one so use `[0]`, if there's multiple then you should loop through them.. updating my answer.

Comment: Oh ok I'll go try it

Comment: @UdayKiran doesn't matter if there's only one or if there's many. getElement(S)ByClassName will always return an array. it's up to you to decide which of those array entries you need to use.